# Can <filesystem> and respectively <experimental/filesystem> be used for both Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, c++-experimental

I am looking for a cross-platform (nothing weird, standard Linux and Windows installations for desktop) way of working with directories and files (example: list the contents of a directory, check if a path is a file or directory etc.). I don't want to use any `boost`, `Qt` etc.

So after some research I found out about the `<filesystem>` header. Since I use C++14 I checked and found out that pre-standard implementation (the `filesystem` functionality became part of the C++ standard with C++17) it can be found (or at least so far the parts that I use) as `<experimental/filesystem>`.

My knowledge in terms of Windows and Visual C++ are quite lacking so my question is does this apply also to it or just GCC and Clang (the ones I've tried so far)? I know that when using `cmake` I need to distinguish between Clang and GCC when linking (see also this [bug report](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17834) from 3 years ago):

```
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} c++experimental)
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} stdc++fs)
endif()
```

I don't know how to handle Visual C++ in this case. My project needs to be as portable as possible given a specific standard for C++.

---

**NOTE:** I don't want to use C++17 but I want to add the possibility for a support for it in my code IF someone builds it with that standard enabled. That is why distinguishing between C++14 and C++17 is important.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 all you need to do is enable c++17. There is no extra library to link.

Comment: Indeed. The the `filesystem` system header is available with the C++14 standard, however this header is effectively empty until you upgrade to C++17. Could be done via `if(MSVC) set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17) endif()` (assuming you're not already unconditionally using the C++17 standard.)

Comment: For max "portability", do you need your code to be buildable in C++14 AND in C++17 as well? If not, MSVC should be able to build correctly without any additional target indeed.

Comment: I'm not really comfortable using anything "experimental" in code publicly released or, <insert deity of choice> forbid, shipped to clients.

Comment: @fabian sounds like an answer!

Comment: @user4581301 The code is for a demo. My machine is ancient so compiling a new gcc, clang or whatever is not an option. Plus I don't have Windows. :D

Comment: @fabian In C++14 at least on Linux you use `<experimental/filesystem>`. I can't check for Visual C++ anyway since I don't have Windows plus cross-compilation setup is too tedious for the time I have. I chose C++14 because I have support for it on my machine and the features, I want to use, are available (even if marked as experimental). In addition `__has_header` is for some reason not working so I'm going with a check for the `__cplusplus` value in the preprocessor hoping that the header is available (in a typical setup this should be the case).

Comment: Are you refering to `__has_include` (which is added in C++ 17 too, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include). However since you want to stay with C++14 and the C++14 does not provide the functionality defined in the `<filesystem>` header via that API, you'll probably need special handling for all the compilers you want to support. (if it's possible to use this API at all in all of them)

Comment: @fabian Ah, dang it. All of the examples I found had it even though these were using C++14's experimental.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better not.

From [MSVC STL source](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/47cd70315d560e4fe1ac699c0eb8ec8bfc5cb658/stl/inc/experimental/filesystem#L27-L31):

> The <experimental/filesystem> header providing
> std::experimental::filesystem is deprecated by Microsoft and will be
> REMOVED. It is superseded by the C++17  header providing
> std::filesystem.

So it will be an issue with future Visual Studio versions.

I guess the best option is to switch to C++17.

Common alternative is `<boost/filesystem>`. Less common alternative is another cross-platform library, such as Qt.

Comment: I do add the `<filesystem>` but conditionally in the preprocessor. If I have C++14 then I use `<experimental/filesystem>`. In addition I added a namespace alias so that regardless of the header and change of the namespace the rest of the code doesn't change. Last but not least I explicitly wrote I don't want to use `boost`, `Qt` etc. so mentioning that in the answer in not really helpful.